# Android - Send data from MainActivity to Thread

Tags: android, android-thread

in my Android app I need to send any changes from my UI to a thread.
User changes a textview and I need to get value and sent to thread processing. Is it possible ?
I have see only solutions from thread to UI (via `runOnUiThread`), but not UI to thread.

Comment: You can use `Sharedpreference` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write your own custom `Thread`

```
public static class MyThread extends Thread{
        Object yourData;
        // write your get/set data
        // override the run function.
}
```

After that, you can change your thread easily. However, you should remember that you can not reuse the thread.